# Rails model attributes best-practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, attributes

I have a user model to which I want to add 4 time fields to correspond to **morning**, **noon**, **evening** & **night**.

So I could for example do this :

```
=> @user.morning = Time.now.to_s(:time)
=> @user.morning
=> "08:00"
```

I'm just wondering about best practices here..should I use an array/hash to store these times as one attribute or just add 4 separate attributes to the model?

I use all 4 values together (not individually)

so it would probably be better to do something like this

```
@user.times.each do |t|
  ....
end
```

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: I think any answer really depends on the use case. I can't really see a good case where you would want to store this on the user model if it is something like reservations or preferred times. I'm would use 4 different fields for future proofing. You never know when you need to query using one of the times. As far as I know the native HSTORE and JSON types don't support date types for values so you will have to do casting manually and you can't use the databases date/time functions.

Comment: Thanks Max, appreciate the info